# Which headers are relevant to me in NDK toolchain?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to use the openMP header, but I see that there are many omp.h, in different folders. I am  confused, I only target "regular" devices such as galaxy or xperia. Which folder should I use ? I guess ARM but there are 4 ARM folders (4.6, 4.8, clang 3.3 clang 3.4).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your NDK module declaration inside *Android.mk*:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fopenmp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp
```

Then, inside your app, just use `#include <omp.h>`.

With the latest NDK, by default the GCC 4.8 toolchain will be used.
Then the right *omp.h* will be included for each platform you're compiling for (x86, armeabi-v7a, x86_64, arm64-v8a...) with the NDK.

If you want to change which toolchain is used, you can tune the `APP_TOOLCHAIN` and `APP_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` variables inside *Application.mk*.